# yacc shift-reduce for ambiguous lambda syntax

Tags: parsing, go, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm writing a grammar for a toy language in Yacc (the one packaged with Go) and I have an expected shift-reduce conflict due to the following pseudo-issue. I have to distilled the problem grammar down to the following.

```
start:
  stmt_list

expr:
  INT | IDENT | lambda | '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2 }

lambda:
  '(' params ')' '{' stmt_list '}'

params:
  expr | params ',' expr

stmt:
  /* empty */ | expr

stmt_list:
  stmt | stmt_list ';' stmt
```

A lambda function looks something like this:

```
map((v) { v * 2 }, collection)
```

My parser emits:

> conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

Given the input:

```
(a)
```

It correctly parses an `expr` by the `'(' expr ')'` rule. However given an input of:

```
(a) { a }
```

(Which would be a lambda for the identity function, returning its input). I get:

> syntax error: unexpected '{'

This is because when `(a)` is read, the parser is choosing to reduce it as `'(' expr ')'`, rather than consider it to be `'(' params ')'`. Given this conflict is a shift-reduce and not a reduce-reduce, I'm assuming this is solvable. I just don't know how to structure the grammar to support this syntax.

EDIT | It's ugly, but I'm considering defining a token so that the lexer can recognize the ')' '{' sequence and send it through as a single token to resolve this.

EDIT 2 | Actually, better still, I'll make lambdas require syntax like `->(a, b) { a * b}` in the grammar, but have the lexer emit the `->` rather than it being in the actual source code.

Comment: Are statements not separated by punctuation? IOW, if `(v) {v*2}` is not a lambda, what is it? A `stmt_list` or something else? Please add a bit more grammar to the question.

Comment: There are no semicolons between statements (they are actually comments, as in lisp. New lines are effectively end-of-statement indicators, as in Go or JavaScript.

Comment: This does pose some complexity in the grammar, as newlines may occur, for example in argument lists. Maybe this is what's getting me into trouble. I just know its complaining about the '{' right after its reduced the argument list as an expr.

Comment: I could post the entire grammar, but obviously it's long and hard to distill down to the root cause of the conflict.

Comment: Actually TBH I haven't tried writing a tiny grammar with this issue in isolation. That would help. I'll do that and probably have a lightbulb moment :)

Comment: It's pretty difficult to provide advice about how to fix a problem without actual details, so I'm not going to try. You need to *at least* answer my direct question: if `(v){v*2}` is not a lambda, what is it? Or, if you prefer, what valid derivation can start `(v){...`? BTW, newlines are not end-of-statement indicators in Go and Javascript; semicolons are, and the grammar reflects that fact. The Go rules are simple enough to be implemented by the lexical scanner, which would be my recommendation. The JS rule is trickier. If your problem is really about ASI, please ask a different question :)

Comment: ... So you might just start by writing the grammar without trying to deal with ASI or newlines; if that works, then the question is really how to perform the ASI.

Comment: Thanks @rici you're right, there's not enough info here to resolve this. I'm gonna distill it down and rewrite the question. In response to your question "then what is it?", the entire construct can only be a lambda. If new lines were not required between statements, however, the (v) would be the expr `v`, and the { v * 2 } would be a set. However they shouldn't be allowed side-by-side in the same expression like this. I'll distill it down with a smaller grammar and rewrite or delete this question, thanks :)

Comment: Cool. Sounds like your newline handling isn't wirking. I suggest you write the grammar as though statement separators were required and then figure out the best way to fabricate the tokens, which is my approach to parsing JS, for example.

Comment: @rici I've updated my question with a minimal problem grammar. I've also removed ASI handling from the equation and just focusing on a single line of input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is indeed correct; although the grammar is not ambiguous, it is impossible for the parser to decide with the input reduced to `( <expr>` and with lookahead `)` whether or not the `expr` should be reduced to `params` before shifting the `)` or whether the `)` should be shifted as part of a `lambda`. If the next token were visible, the decision could be made, so the grammar LR(2), which is outside of the competence of go/yacc.

If you were using bison, you could easily solve this problem by requesting a GLR parser, but I don't believe that go/yacc provides that feature.

There is an LR(1) grammar for the language (there is always an LR(1) grammar corresponding to any LR(k) grammar for any value of `k`) but it is rather annoying to write by hand. The essential idea of the LR(k) to LR(1) transformation is to shift the reduction decisions k-1 tokens forward by accumulating k-1 tokens of context into each production. So in the case that `k` is 2, each production P: `N → α` will be replaced with productions `TNU → Tα U` for each `T` in `FIRST(α)` and each `U` in `FOLLOW(N)`. [See Note 1] That leads to a considerable blow-up of non-terminals in any non-trivial grammar.

Rather than pursuing that idea, let me propose two much simpler solutions, both of which you seem to be quite close to.

First, in the grammar you present, the issue really is simply the need for a two-token lookahead when the two tokens are <kbd>)</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>. That could easily be detected in the lexer, and leads to a solution which is still hacky but a simpler hack: Return `){` as a single token. You need to deal with intervening whitespace, etc., but it doesn't require retaining any context in the lexer. This has the added bonus that you don't need to define `params` as a list of `expr`s; they can just be a list of `IDENT` (if that's relevant; a comment suggests that it isn't).

The alternative, which I think is a bit cleaner, is to extend the solution you already seem to be proposing: accept a little too much and reject the errors in a semantic action. In this case, you might do something like:

```
start:
  stmt_list

expr:
    INT
  | IDENT
  | lambda
  | '(' expr_list ')'
        { // If $2 has more than one expr, report error
          $$ = $2
        }

lambda:
  '(' expr_list ')' '{' stmt_list '}'
        { // If anything in expr_list is not a valid param, report error
          $$ = make_lambda($2, $4)
        }

expr_list:
  expr | expr_list ',' expr

stmt:
  /* empty */ | expr

stmt_list:
  stmt | stmt_list ';' stmt
```

#### Notes

1. That's only an outline; the complete algorithm includes the mechanism to recover the original parse tree. If `k` is greater than 2 then `T` and `U` are strings the the `FIRSTk-1` and `FOLLOWk-1` sets.

Comment: Great answer @rici, thanks. The parameters in my functions are valid exprs as the language is pattern matched and the patterns are entirely arbitrary. Both the solutions you suggest are up for consideration. What I'm actually thinking at this point (as it's easy for the lexer to spot) is to define an imaginary token `PARAMS` and emit that right before the ')' if followed by '{'. Then the grammar just needs to expect `'(' params PARAMS ')'`, where that PARAMS token is just some virtual sentinel that the lexer spits out.

Comment: @d11wtq: Yes, you could insert a fake token. Or you could change the `)` to `CLOSE_PARAMS`. Or you could combine the two tokens into one. I've used the latter two strategies; the first one seems like unnecessary overhead to me, since it doesn't do anything to simplify either the grammar or the lexer. Either way, the lexer needs to read ahead after it sees a `)`. The combined token solution is the easiest if your parser pulls tokens from the lexer; if the lexer pushes tokens to the parser, then there is little difference in lexer complexity (but I don't think go yacc supports that).

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a shift-reduce conflict, and you want only the shift behavior, your parser generator may give you a way to prefer a shift vs. a reduce.  This is classically how the conflict for grammar rules for "if-then-stmt" and "if-then-stmt-else-stmt" is resolved, when the if statement can also be a statement.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Shift_002fReduce.html

You can get this effect two ways:
a)  Count on the accidental behavior of the parsing engine.
   If an LALR parser handles shifts first, and then reductions if there are no shifts, then you'll get this "prefer shift" for free.   All the parser generator has to do is built the parse tables anyway, even if there is a detected conflict.
b)  Enforce the accidental behavior.   Design (or a get a) parser generator to accept "prefer shift on token T".  Then one can supress the ambiguity.  One still have to implement the parsing engine as in a) but that's pretty easy.

I think this is easier/cleaner than abusing the lexer to make strange tokens (and that doesn't always work anyway).

Obviously, you could make a preference for reductions to turn it the other way.  With some extra hacking, you could make shift-vs-reduce specific the state in which the conflict occured; you can even make it specific to the pair of conflicting rules but now the parsing engine needs to keep preference data around for nonterminals.  That still isn't hard.   Finally, you could add a predicate for each nonterminal which is called when a shift-reduce conflict is about to occur, and it have it provide a decision.

The point is you don't have to accept "pure" LALR parsing; you can bend it easily in a variety of ways, if you are willing to modify the parser generator/engine a little bit.    This gives a really good reason to understand how these tools work; then you can abuse them to your benefit.

Comment: I don't see how shift/reduce preference can help here. The grammar is LR(2); sometimes a shift is necessary and sometimes a reduce. So the solution is to use a GLR (or LALR(2)) parser, or rewrite the grammar so that it's LR(1), or abuse the lexer, or accept a superset and throw an error in the action. The first option is apparently unavailable for Go; the second one is a pain, and therefore the fourth one is my preference; I say so in my answer. But option 3 is possible, too, and a not uncommon solution to LR(2) grammars. (Bison does it, for example, to parse its own input.)

Comment: If it really is LR(2) with sometimes-shift, sometimes-reduce, then my solution doesn't apply.  I took OP's word that he had a (simple) shift-reduce conflict.   The semantic reduction predicate may help even if it is LR(2), if the lexer is willing to read ahead several tokens (required by LR(2) anyway).  For the example grammar given, it appears that a "prefer to shift on {" resolves the problem.  What am I missing?

Comment: By the time you see `{`, it's too late to shift because you don't have `( params )` on the stack. You have `( expr )`. The decision to shift or reduce which creates the conflict was with respect to the `)`; since the default is to shift, you're guaranteed to have `( expr )`, but that cannot be followed by `{`. In order to create the conditions for accepting `{`, you need to have reduced `expr` to `params` prior to shifting the `)`. To make that shift/reduce decision (about the `)`), you need to know what follows the `)` -- two tokens of lookahead. Neither shift nor reduce is always right.

Comment: You could fix that by manipulating the grammar; it's not *that* difficult, but it's not pretty. OTOH, allowing `expr: '(' params ')'` and then checking in the semantic actcion that `params` never used the  `params: params ',' expr` production is pretty straightforward, and avoids the question of deciding whether or not to reduce `params: expr` before the `)`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the reduction to expr. OK,my solution doesn't work.  I like your '(' params ')' as expr with semantic check.   I'm leaving my answer because it is useful for resolving some situations. Upvotes not expected.