# How to identify whether a grammar is LR(n), LL(n)

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar, lr-grammar

For a language that is not `LL(1)` or `LR(1)` how can one try to find out if some number `n` exists such that the grammar can be `LL(n)` or `LR(n)`?

You check if a grammar is `LR(0)` by looking at the canonical collection of `LR(0)` items. Then, assuming it wasn't `LR(0)`, you can check if it is `LR(1)` by introducing the lookahead symbol. My simple reasoning tells me that, to check whether it is `LR(2)` or not, you probably have to make the lookahead contain the next two symbols instead of just one. For `LR(3)` you have to take three symbols into consideration etc.

Even if this is the case, even though I doubt it, I am struggling to think of how can one try to identify (or even get a hint at) an `n`, or the non-existence thereof, for which a specific grammar can be `LR(n)` and/or `LL(n)` without checking incrementally from an arbitary `LR(m)` upwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If a *language* is LR(*k*) for some *k*>1, then it is LR(1). (That's not true for a grammar, of course.) That is, if you have an LR(*k*) grammar for a language, then you can mechanically construct an LR(1) grammar which allows you to recover the original parse tree. This is not true of LL(*k*); LL(*k*) languages are a strict subset of LL(*k*+1) languages.
2. The test you propose will indeed let you decide whether a *grammar* is LR(*k*) for some given k (or LL(*k*)). Unfortunately, there's no way of figuring out the smallest possible value of *k* other than the successive search you propose, and there is no guarantee that the search will ever terminate.
3. Although the problem is hard (or impossible) in the general case, it can often be answered for specific grammars, by considering the possible valid successors of a grammar state which exhibits conflicts.

In most real-world grammars, there will only be a few conflicts, so manual examination of conflicting states is possible. In general terms, one needs to figure out the path which led to the conflicting state, and the possible continuations. In many cases it will be clear that the parsing conflict could be resolved with slightly more lookahead.

A large class of grammars where this will fail is the set of ambiguous grammars. An ambiguous grammar cannot be LR(k) (or LL(k)) for any *k*. Again, the question of whether a grammar is ambiguous is not decidable but effective heuristics exist, some of which are included in commercial products.

Again, it is often easy to find ambiguities in real-world grammars, either by visual inspection (as above), or by feeding a lot of valid texts into a GLR parser (such as the one produced by bison) until an ambiguity is reported. (Alternatively, you can enumerate valid texts from the grammar with a straight-forward algorithm, and see if a text appears twice in the enumeration.)

Here are a couple of possibly relevant SO questions illustrating analysis techniques. I'm sure there are more.

[A yacc shift/reduce conflict on an unambiguous grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19335353/1566221)

[Bison reduce/reduce situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41095428/1566221)

[yacc shift-reduce for ambiguous lambda syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39301979/1566221)

[How to understand and fix conflicts in PLY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41775631/1566221)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on point No3? What are the features that one should be looking for on the successors? Also, what can be done in regards to LL grammars?

Comment: If I test a grammar and find that it isn't LR(1) , LR(2) , LR(3) (...) , at some point I should start looking for specific characteristics that could help build a case that this grammar might not be LR at all. Would such characteristics exist and if yes what would they look like? If that is possible, would  something similar be doable for the LL case?

Comment: @Eternal_Light: I tried to address your questions but I fear that it is still rather unspecific. There are a number of examples of non-LR(1) grammars in SO, most of them with the question "How do I resolve this conflict", and quite a few of them have been analysed in answers. I don't usually bother with LL conflicts, so I can't help you much there; it is much more common for LL parsers to require unbounded lookahead and the usual solution is to switch to an LR parser.

Comment: Thank you very much for extending your answer. I find its insight really valuable. I have one last question that I hope you might be able to answer: could a grammar be unambiguous and still not be LR or can I safely infer its LR-ness from its unambiguity?

Comment: A grammar can be unambiguous and not LR(k) for any *k*. The simplest example is the language of palindromes, with productions `S -> a` and `S -> a S a` for each alphabetic symbol `a`, plus `S -> ε`.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help :)